# git is forcing to pull even i am the only one making changes in branch

Tags: git, git-config

I have one problem currently on WSL. I am using git - following scenario

```
- I checkout to branch1
- user1 did last commit in branch1
- I pull changes
- I make changes
- I add files and commit
- I try to push
- Git forces me to pull even there is no change since last pull
- I pull changes
- merge commit created
- in git there are 2 commits: 1st by user1 (with my changes), 2nd by me (no changes, just merge commit)
```

Can anybody help me with this? I have my global git user in git config defined. I am not sure why is this happening. Should I configure local user for git for each repo? (It happens on all repos I currently have. Note: I used this setup - wsl/git in the past and it worked ok - so i guess this is just some configuration issue)

## UPDATE

message after push

```
To xxx/xxx.git
 ! [rejected]        branch1 -> branch1 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@xxx/xxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Could you post the message that git gives when trying to push? Also can you give more details regarding the branch for each command (at least when pulling and pushing)?

Comment: When Git asks for a pull, you could run `git fetch origin branch1 && git log FETCH_HEAD..HEAD` to check the commits that do not exist in the local `branch1` yet.

Comment: i posted after post message - in update

Comment: You can do `git pull origin <remote-branch-name>` to make your local branch  in sync with remote .